# Redirecting my WordPress site from wordpress.com

Tags: redirects, wordpress

I need to redirect my WordPress site hosted on wordpress.com to my new domain hosted on another provider. How does that redirection function on this type of site and hosting?

I know how to do that via cPanel (301 redirect) on other hosting companies, but I am not quite clear if wordpress.com functions like other commercial hosting companies.